# \bsc{} inside \addstarredchapter not working

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, minitoc

I try to add chapter name "Introduction" in the Contents
with this command but it's not working:

```
\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\addstarredchapter{\bsc{Introduction} \bsc{Générale}}
```

but it's working with this command:

```
\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\addstarredchapter{\textit{Introduction} \textit{Générale}}
```

How I can fix it?

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, svgnames]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents 
\dominitoc

\chapter*{Introduction générale}
% \addstarredchapter{\bsc{Introduction} \bsc{Générale}}
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bsc{Introduction} \bsc{Générale}} % also with this not working
\addstarredchapter{\textit{Introduction} \bsc{Générale}} % first ok second no

%\minitoc

\section*{intro1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{intro1}
\lipsum
\section*{intro2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{intro2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend this into a full minimal exmaple. For example where does `\addstarredchapter` come from, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @daleif Isn't `\addstarredchapter` from KOMA bundle?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that is my guess, but I never use KOMA, so that information is needed in the question.

Comment: Minitoc? My guess

Comment: yes I use minitoc

Comment: The cause is the `babel` definition of `\bsc`: `\let\bsc\textsc`, so this does not work ...

Answer (score 1):

The `babel-french` documentation reveals that `\bsc` stands for `boxed small caps` so this is not italic.

Looking into the code of `babel-french.ldf` it is seen that `\bsc` is defined as

`\let\bsc\textsc`

The reason, why the text does not appear in small caps is due the the `\bfseries` statement in (hidden in the `\addstarredchapter` command etc.) and even `lmodern` does not provide a bold small caps font.

So `\addstarredchapter{\textit{Introduction}}` (etc.) is the correct way if text should appear with italic font in the ToC.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{lmodern}




\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents 
\dominitoc


\chapter*{Introduction générale}
%\addstarredchapter{\bsc{Introduction Générale}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bsc{Introduction} \bsc{Générale}} % also with this not working
\addstarredchapter{\textit{Introduction Générale}} % first ok second no



%\minitoc

\section*{intro1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{intro1}
\lipsum
\section*{intro2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{intro2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for answering.  yes it work with `\textit` from the beging,  but I Want it work with `\bsc`

Answer (score 1):

There is no boldface small caps font in the Latin Modern family and indeed you get

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/lmr/bx/n' instead on input line 2.
```

With

```
\addstarredchapter{\normalfont\bsc{Introduction} \bsc{Générale}}
```

you go through, but it's wrong to begin with. You probably want to set *all* chapter titles in the table of contents to small caps: it makes no sense to do it for just the introduction.

Comment: thank you, but actualy, not for all chapter titles but just for introduction and conclusion. how i can do that?

Comment: @AnsPiter As I said, it makes very little sense, if any.